# mysql query group by totals

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am using the following query to retrieve the number of events per state from 2 tables that are linked by a userID.

```
SELECT state,COUNT(*) AS num 
FROM tableUserInfo
WHERE userID IN (SELECT userID  
                 FROM tableEvents 
                 WHERE conditionOne = 1 
                   AND conditionTwo = 2) 
GROUP BY state
```

This query works correctly. My problem is that not all states have user entries, and I need the query to return 0 for those.  I was wondering if there was a method such as joining or using an in clause, that would included a set of all states, making the query return 0 for any that didn't have entries in tableEvents?

Comment: Hint: LEFT JOIN

Comment: The query above should be using an INNER JOIN rather than a sub-query.

Comment: What is a user entry? (Tableevents? tableuserinfo?) Are you saying not all states are in tbluserInfo?  if not, what is the source for all states?  I'd like to see some sample data and expected results.  The question seems clear at first but on second view there's lots of ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1):

As @raymond-nijland suggested you can use Left Join to include all states.

```
SELECT tableUserInfo.state,COUNT(tableUserInfo.*) AS num 
FROM tableUserInfo Left Join tableEvents on tableUserInfo.userID = tableEvents.userID 
WHERE tableEvents.conditionOne = 1 AND tableEvents.conditionTwo = 2
GROUP BY state
```

Comment: I understand this. Thanks.  I assume the join is a more efficient query than the subquery I am currently using. My problem is that a state may not be represented by any users in the event table. So my query returns the number of entries for each state, but if possible I need it to return 0 for the states that aren't represented.  I could get at list of all states from a 3rd table, or from a query like "select distinct(state) from tableUserInfo", but I don't known how to incorporate this into my query.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a list of states? If not then this would give a list of all the states your database knows about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state FROM tableUserInfo
```

....and enclosing this in brackets it can be dropped in place in the query below:

```
SELECT s.state, IFNULL(cnt, 0) AS num
FROM list_of_states s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT state,COUNT(*) AS cnt 
    FROM tableUserInfo ui
    INNER JOIN tableEvents te
    ON ui.userId=te.userId
    WHERE conditionOne = 1 
    AND conditionTwo = 2
    GROUP BY state
) u
ON s.state=u.state;
```

Although in the absence of "list_of_states" it would be more efficient to do this:

```
SELECT ui.state, SUM(IF(te.userId IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS cnt 
FROM tableUserInfo ui
LEFT JOIN tableEvents te
   ON ui.userId=te.userId
   AND te.conditionOne = 1 
   AND te.conditionTwo = 2
GROUP BY state;
```

Comment: I got this to work with a subquery fetching a state list. Thank you very much!  I tried so many variations of this it was making my head spin a little.